# What format to use to insert body measurement in English system of measurements?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Im working on Android App for tracking/logging daily body weight measurements and want to support International (kg and g) and English (lbs and oz) system units.

For the International units I need only one EditText controller for decimal input of the weight measurement in kg (for instance 75.00)

For the English units I'm little bit unsure if I should have one EditText where the user sets measurement in lbs as decimal, or if I should have two EditTexts. One for lbs and second for oz. As far as I know, people usually talk about 165 lbs 5.55 oz (for 75 kg) and not 165.347 lbs.

Anyone using the English units daily that can give me some input on this question?

Comment: Is this for people's weights?  Normally only newborn babies are measured in lbs. and ounces.  An adult would track their weight in lbs., to the nearest 1/2 or 1/4 lb.

Comment: I would implement a tricky parser that tries to parse the whole "n lbs n oz" string from a single field.

Comment: I've been [re-]thinking about Bill's comment and think it is very true. I would find it a bit odd if I had to enter my weight with an ounce component. (Baby - and Food - measurements tend to be different and usually have a good bit less mass where more precision is desired.)

Comment: Bill -  My scales shows ounces or 0,1 kg, so this level of detail is common, in Europe at any rate.

Comment: @pst and Bill: so you suggest that I use one input field with decimals and lbs as unit?

Comment: @SList You know the oz precision on a [human] scale [is a lie](http://askville.amazon.com/weight-fluctuate-2--pounds-day/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=9992022) .. right? ;-)

Comment: Ismar - for the weight that you gave, I would use either the British or American format as I described below, with oz.  But the oz should be a round number.  Even a weight fanatic like me does not get interested in 0,55 oz.

Comment: (All I'm saying, is, if I saw a "lbs" fields that took 0-2 decimal place, I would be as comfortable entering `135`, `135.5`, or `135.25` and think nothing of it.)

Comment: @pst so you would preffer 3 fields: stone, lbs and oz - all round numbers (not decimals)? Or would it be strange to enter the weight in lbs as 0-2 decimals? I will anyway _display_ the measurements in format n lbs n oz, so my question is only related for _entering_ the values.

Comment: @IsmarSlomic It depends on what was being measured. I would never use [stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_(unit)) (that's so English!), and I wouldn't use oz for entering my weight. I would only "expect" to see lbs+oz on things in say the 2-10lb (number pulled out of my hat) range where such precision mattered.

Comment: Ismar - look on some internet weight tracking programs and see what units they use, eg http://www.bbc.co.uk/health/tools/bmi_calculator/bmi.shtml

Comment: @pst OK, thanks for the input. So to summarize, if measuring the body weight of the baby (lets say weight between 0-10kg) I could use two fields; one for lbs and second for oz to have better precision. When measuring adults body weight i could only use lbs with no decimals?

Comment: @IsmarSlomic That sounds good to me. However, take into account how many baby weights will be entered - and for what purpose. Is this application for measuring newborn babies? (Those suckers grow fast! :) It might be easiest just to force all measurements .. that is, know the [primary] domain and the cost of supporting alternatives.

Comment: @pst well i don't want to restrict the use of my application. I want it to be used by both, newborn babies and adults. I got baby myself this year, and we did mass measurement every week. We really missed one simple app for tracking all these measurements. I could skip the oz and only support lbs, but then I loose precision of 450 grams, which could be a lot for someone wanting to loose weight. Reducing 200 or 300 gram one days is a lot...

Comment: @IsmarSlomic Ahh, but that's a valuable business opportunity! A "life tracker" app that will evolve - e.g. through purchased upgrades - to support the current relevant data! :) So, first as a baby, measures with lbs+oz (and whatever else people like to measure about a baby) and shows pretty baby graphics and then "evolves" to a kid version and then a .. ;-)

Comment: @pst You are probably right. I might need to scope creep the domain of my app(s). I actually thought on providing the app for free, because I mainly to the development to learn the Android development platform and of course create something useful for me and others. Anyone, thanks for your valuable inputs!

Answer (score 1):

I would use 11 [stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_%28unit%29) 11 lbs 5.55 oz (I am English), especially if it is a person's weight.
I think 165 lbs 5.55 oz is American.
You are right, both are better than 165.347 lbs.